# split string using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string "What is your name?" in a variable like as shown below.

```
String str="What is your name ?";
String[] splitString =str.split("\\is+");
```

I want to split the string in such a way that I want only those words between **is** and **?**. ie. `your` and `name` by using regular expression

can anyone tell me some solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
String str="What is your name ?";
String[] splitString = str.replaceAll(".*? is (.*) \\?", "$1").split(" ");
// [your, name]
```

**[IdeOne demo](https://ideone.com/UeBDpA)**

Update: if you want to match case insensitive, just add the insensitive flag:

```
String str="What is your name ?";
String[] splitString = str.replaceAll("(?i).*? is (.*) \\?", "$1").split(" ");
```

Comment: how about if `is` is case sensitive

Comment: @AlexMan updated my answer. You have to add insensitive flag with `(?i)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do replacing and splitting.

```
 string.replaceFirst(".*\\bis\\b\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\?.*", "$1").split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

The poor mans solution would be to extract the substing first and use the split on top of that:

```
String substring = str.substring(str.indexOf("is")+2,str.indexOf("?"));
String[] splitString =substring.trim().split(" ");
```

Comment: do substring have int and string parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceFirst` and then `split`

```
String str="What is your name?";
String[] splitString =str.replaceFirst(".*[[Ii][Ss]]\\s+","").split("\\s*\\?.*|\\s+");
for (int i=0; i< splitString.length; i++){
    System.out.println("-"+splitString[i]);
}
```

`replaceFirst` is needed to delete the first part of string, which is `What is`. The regex `.*[[Ii][Ss]]\\s+` means - any signs before case insensitive IS and all the spaces after that. If it'll stay, we will get an additional empty string while splitting.

After replacing, it splits the rest string by

`\\s+` one or more whitespaces

and

`\\s*\\?.*` the `?` sign with all whitespaces before and any characters after

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `is([^\?]+)` and capture the first subgroup and split it 
    This is a slightly longer approach, but is the right way to do this in core Java. You can use a regex library to do this

```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    //Later
    String pattern="`is([^\?]+)"
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
    var words=m.group(1)
```

Comment: how to write that , `str.split("\\is([^\?]+)")` is giving exception